# string array from onpostexecute to mainactivity

Tags: android, arrays, listview

It's been a while that I'm strugling with a question:

At this point I'm able to:

1-make custom listview with data from my database - this part has been acomplished.
2-make a custom listview with search filter.

So, I'm trying to make a custom listview with a search filter at this point.

The thing is that I'm struggling hard and I don't have much time and the only solution I've found for this was:

On onPostExecute, I run the following code :

```
  for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length();i++){
            JSONObject json = null;
            try {
                json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                listId.add(json.getString("id"));
                listNome.add(json.getString("name"));
                listTipo.add(json.getString("type"));
          } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



        }

        String[] arrId = listId.toArray(new String[listId.size()]);//StringArray de ID's
        String[] arrName = listNome.toArray(new String[listName.size()]); // 
        String[] arrType = listTipo.toArray(new String[listType.size()]);

        tvJson.setText(Arrays.toString(arrName)); 

        Intent i = new Intent (MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("KEY_ID", arrId);
        i.putExtra("KEY_TIPO", arrTipo);
        i.putExtra("KEY_NOME", arrNome);
        startActivity(i);   

    }
```

As you can see this is not a perfect solution but I need those string arrays to make my customlistview.

If I have them on The NextActivity all my code runs smoothly, the thing is, I dont want to start an activity, I want to get this arrays to Main Activity and after that build my listview.

So, is there any way I can send this 3 string[]'s to MainActivity?

PS: It's not the most elegant code ever but I'm new to this and I have deadlines to follow for a project - that's the main reason I'm not trying to rewrite all this code.

Comment: Send a broadcast back to your activity and receive it with a BroadcastReceiver or have your AsyncTask be a subclass of the Activity you want to use it with and call a method directly passing the strings array as the parameters.

Comment: Any code on that first sugestion?

Comment: [look this for broadcast receiver example](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regards to a broadcast, you need to setup your activity to be prepared to receive a broadcast. Add this to your MainActivity:

```
private SimpleBroadcastReceiver mReceiver;

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    mReceiver = new SimpleBroadcastReceiver();
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter("com.your_package.package.SOME_KEY"));
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
}

public class SimpleBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         // Get your intent extras like you were doing in your new activity
    }
}
```

Now your MainActivity is ready to receive broadcasts, filtering for the action `"com.your_package.package.SOME_KEY"`. Now you just need to send the broadcast from your onPostExecute(). However, to do this you need access to the applications context. To do this you can create a constructor for your AsyncTask class that gets a context as it's parameter

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    private Context context;

    public MyAsyncTask(Context context){
         this.context = context;
    }
}
```

You can now take advantage of this AsyncTask from an Activity as follows

```
new MyAsyncTask(this).execute();
```

Now you have access to your context, you can finish up `onPostExecute()` as follows:

```
//in onPostExecute instead of starting your new activity
Intent i = new Intent("com.your_package.package.SOME_KEY");
context.sendBroadcast(i);
```

Obviously this will need some modification to fit what you are doing, but it is the general idea.